# Android: Almacenamiento interno disponible

Tags: java, android

Para poder ejecutar un proceso que genera muchos archivos debo asegurarme que tengo el espacio de almacenamiento disponible, esto en base a unas estimaciones y cálculos que me dan una cifra aproximada del espacio que debo tener para poder ejecutar el proceso.

Eventualmente también debo poder conocer el espacio de almacenamiento interno, por ejemplo el que usan las aplicaciones cuando insertan registros en su base de datos o cualquier cosa que se guarde en `getApplicationInfo().dataDir`.

Con el almacenamiento externo no tengo problema, he realizado pruebas duplicando y triplicando fotografías, videos y audios y la cifra se calcula correctamente. Pero el espacio interno (o el que se supone que debe ser) no varía si por ejemplo; accedo a la carpeta /data/data/app.package/ y duplico y triplico el contenido de algún archivo de gran tamaño que se encuentre allí.

Por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente salida:

```
//Inicial
04-22 16:06:10.662: I/System.out(7411): External 2.38 Gb, Internal 468.32 Mb
//Se copia carpeta de 16MB
04-22 16:09:10.476: I/System.out(7411): External 2.36 Gb, Internal 468.32 Mb
//Se copia carpeta de 32MB
04-22 16:12:04.349: I/System.out(7411): External 2.34 Gb, Internal 468.32 Mb
//Se copia archivo de +500MB y se desinstala Facebook (pesa 136MB)
04-22 16:27:26.924: I/System.out(23762): External 1.69 Gb, Internal 468.32 Mb
//Se instala app de 136MB
04-22 16:38:39.571: I/System.out(28209): External 1.61 Gb, Internal 468.32 Mb
//Se instala Word
04-22 16:56:00.658: I/System.out(31925): External 1.46 Gb, Internal 468.32 Mb
```

Notar como **External** si varia de acuerdo a lo que coloque en la SD, pero **Internal** no varía si instalo apps o altero su carpeta data/data, sigue siendo 468.32 MB.

El código que ocupo es el siguiente:

```
public static long checkInternalUsage() {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath());
    long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();
    return bytesAvailable;
}
```

Sé de antemano que los métodos `getBlockSize` y demás están `Deprecated` pero en este caso estoy trabajando con un API < 18, me curo en salud de eso.

Si la app (como cualquier otra) se ejecuta en modo `root`, ¿es la sentencia `Environment.getRootDirectory()` la correcta para acceder al espacio que deseo analizar?
Cualquier luz sobre esto es bienvenida!

Answer (score 2):

Rosendo, a través de la clase **[StatFs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/StatFs.html)** podrías obtener el almacenamiento interno disponible...

> Proporciona toda la información sobre el espacio en el sistema de
>   archivos.

Pero en lugar de **`Environment.getRootDirectory()`** usa **`getFilesDir()`**.

ejemplo:

```
File internalStorageFile=getFilesDir();
long espacioDisponibleBytes = new StatFs(internalStorageFile.getPath()).getAvailableBytes();
```

como plus, puede usar un formateador para mostrar la información a tu gusto.

```
String espacioDisponible = Formatter.formatShortFileSize(getApplicationContext(), espacioDisponibleBytes);
```

Como ejemplo, en lugar de obtener el valor:

> 2123510000

obtendrías mediante el formateador el valor:

> 2.1GB

Comment: podrías por favor enfocar un poco más la respuesta a la pregunta, a simple vista no veo algo diferente a lo que ya estoy haciendo. Te lo agradeceré, favor revisar la pregunta y si hay algo en lo que deba ampliar me comentas.

Comment: Ok Rosendo! la he editado: la diferencia es usar getFilesDir().y no Environment.getRootDirectory() !